# Axapta 2009 - how to export cues to another environment?

Tags: axapta

How to export cues to another environment in Dynamics 2009?
I need to move some cues from DEV to TST.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the steps here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362033(v=ax.50).aspx